# Discord.js - Discord bot stopped responding to commands

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to add some new features to my bot, and it didn't end up working. So I removed the new code, and now it won't respond to any commands. It's still online but as I said earlier, it's completely unresponsive. I've looked through the code and I can't find the issue. I'm still new to coding bots so I'm probably missing something.
Here's my main code file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
console.log(message)
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And here's a command file:

````js
function pickOneFrom(array) {
    function pickOneFrom(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    name: 'throw',
    description: 'this is a throw command!',
    execute(message, args) {
      const responses = ['a apple', 'a melon', 'a potato', 'a snowball', 'a spanner', 'a computer'];
  
      message.channel.send(
        `${message.author} threw ${pickOneFrom(responses)} at ${
          message.mentions.users.first() ?? 'everyone'
        }!`,
      );
    },
  };```
````

Comment: Can we have an example of one of your command files?

Comment: I added a command file to the post, hope it helps.

Comment: What’s up with the return array[...]?

Comment: Does it print `Ready!` in the console? Can you add `console.log(message)` after `client.on('message', message => {` ? You should try [`git`](https://git-scm.com/), so when you add something, you can simply rollback without time or mistakes :-)

Comment: Yes, it does print ready. I also added ```console.log(message``` just now.

Comment: ever heard of github? its SOOOO nice: [github](github.com/home)

Comment: @Evergreen doesn't have to be github, any git would be sufficient

Comment: @DanielW. yes of course, you could use bitbucket or a git on your computer (but i would not recommend the last one because you could accidentally delete it)

Answer (score 0):

After looking your code I see that you didn't import `fs` file system to reading commands files to import so you should add it into your code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: So I've added the line, but the problem is still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(client , message , args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

You forgot to add `client` at `client.commands.get(command).execute(message , args)`

Comment: Maybe their execute function doesn't use that

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it still isn't working.

Comment: in your command file add ```client``` at ```execute(message,args)``` that should make your command run